# How do I get the HTTP redirect data when using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

basically I am trying to look at the http redirect data when getting a link with selenium webdriver.

With python requests I would do it like this:

```
r = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=False)
match = re.search(r'some regex', r.headers['Location'])
```

But now the site is behind cloudflare protection, so simple http requests do not work anymore.
Any idea how I could look into the redirect headers with selenium on python?

Another option might be to inject the selenium cookie into the request, but that does not seem as robust.

More details on the redirects:

```
- I send GET request to URL_A
--> I receive redirect response to URL_B (< This is the one i want)
- URL_B is another redirect response to URL_C (I do not want that)
```

Basically I end up on URL_C but I want to know URL_B, so I have to look into the requests headers somehow with selenium

Comment: can you give more details? the actual redirect url is to cloudflare site ? or its hidden... i can advice some complicated method working with browser performance logs, there you can extract each request directly from chrome devtools... but as i said this is too complicated and will take alot of coding.

Comment: As you might know cloudflare adds a 5s wait before page loads. With selenium you can easily circumevent this by just waiting until it redirects you.

Before cloudlfare protection I could just send a http request with requests and see the redirect Location in the header. Now when I send a request it does not have a Location at all because it just gets the Cloudflare load page. 

So I just wanted to use selenium to extract the redirect location for me instead of python requests. But of course when I use selenium it just ends up at the final redirect location, which is not what I want

Comment: to recieve 302 redirect url, loading page has to load and validate there is no access and redirect you to sso page so you can authorize (this is the case when using sso) if its just redirect to another page (static) in that case it will be the same url ?

Comment: added more details